# RocksDBException: does not exist

Tags: rocksdb, rocksdb-java

**Exception:**

```
org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: /vdt/derived: does not exist (create_if_missing is false)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(Native Method)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(RocksDB.java:290)
```

Files (.sst) are present at location /vdt/derived

Need help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

A valid RocksDB directory needs to have options file (`OPTIONS-123`) and manifest file (`MANIFEST-234` and `CURRENT`) to open the sstables, just sst file is not enough.